# Why do the Linux kernel headers contain references to nonexistent headers?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, c, source, header-file

I'm trying to build [IBCS](http://www.jaggycraft.co.uk/linux/ibcs/index.html) ([source here](http://ibcs.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ibcs/ibcs/)) on Ubuntu 15.10 (Linux 4.2.35).

This module is obviously pretty old, because its `CONFIG.i386` file gives `gcc` an option `-m486`, which doesn't exist anymore, but changing to `-march=native` seems to work OK.

The file `emulate.c` contains `#includes` like:

```
#include <linux/config.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
```

On my system, only `linux/version.h` exists. The following seems to work, however:

```
#include "/usr/include/valgrind/config.h"
#include "/usr/include/sepol/module.h"
#include <linux/version.h>
#include </usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-35/include/linux/uaccess.h>
```

(YMMV, of course, if you don't have `sepol`.)

That works, except for `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-35/include/linux/uaccess.h`, the top of which has

```
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
```

Which is not found.

I don't seem to have an `asm` folder in `/usr/include` or `/usr/include/linux`. I do have an `/usr/include/asm_generic`, but it doesn't have `uaccess.h`.

My questions are:

1. Why do the modern kernel headers contain references to (apparently) nonexistent files, rather than providing them itself?
2. Where can I get a version of `asm/uaccess.h` and the other headers needed for compilation?

Comment: Try adding `-I /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/arch/x86/include` to the compiler command line.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Oh, that's worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iBCS is obsolete, has been for a *long* time. Too much has changed in the Linux innards to there be any chance for this to still compile, even on an early 4.x kernel. Today it is  [linux-abi](https://sourceforge.net/projects/linux-abi), but that is dead since 2013. Perhaps one of the binfmt modules does the job today.

Comment: [I know about binfmt](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259376/how-is-mono-magical) :P I stumbled upon [Gilles' comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47495/oldest-binary-working-on-linux#comment66069_47495) on [Oldest binary working on Linux?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/47495/136107), and decided to test it out.

Comment: @tac, that is a *native* binary, iBCS was for running *SCO* binaries.

Comment: I'm aware, I just thought I might point out where the idea appeared to me to use IBCS.